# How can I merge two columns with data where if one column's cell is empty the adjacent cell is full?

Tags: excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Basically like this:

```
ab
0 
 1
 5
9
```

V

```
a
0 
1
5
9
```

How can I quickly merge columns a and b in this way in libreoffice calc?

Comment: I guess I could sum them in a new column....

Answer (score 2):

In **Excel:**

in **V1** enter:

```
=A1 & B1
```

and copy downward.